# Using an array to alter line delimited text file in bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Not sure if this question has already been asked but basically I want to read from a file1 which contains special characters and alter them into a URL encoded version. file2 is a pipe delimited document such as: #|%23.

> So when the script reads from the file1 a "#" it would change this to
>   "%23". There are 174 different characters to recognise so if
>   statements wouldn't be feasible.

Note: I am writing this is bash

I was considering using something like sed or awk however I don't know how I could use this with a text file.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use a language which already has a library that handles URL encoding.

Comment: Please include proper samples of your input files, along with the output you're expecting and the code you've written so far. If that code gets to the point of producing output, please include that as well.  Folks here will be happy to help, but a better question is a dependency for better answers.

Comment: And yes, +1 on chepner's comment. While I suspect what you're suggesting *can* be done, the other question is whether it *should* be done. It sounds as if you're re-inventing a wheel in support of an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F '|' '
   FNR == NR { Trsl[ $1 ] = $2; next}
   FNR != NR { 
      s0 = $0
      for( Char in Trsl) {
         Cnt = split( s0, a0, Char )
         s0 = a0[ 1 ]
         for( i = 2; i <= Cnt; i++) s0 = s0 Trsl[ Char] a0[ i]
         }
      print s0
     }
   ' File2 File1
```

- order of file is important to read the translation file before the file to translate
- assume `|` is not in the special character list
- gsub cannot be used due to unexpected result on meta character
- as @karakfa remark, order of translation (related to File2 entry) is not keep, so some unwanted result could occur if character are used in earlier translated result occur like  -> `%20` and after `%` -> `Percent` will give `Percent20` for an original

Comment: make sure you can control replacement order, if you replace # to %23 first and then % to %25, you will get %2523.

Comment: good point, OP should specify the wanted behviour. If order is important, we should use 2 array instead of one and manage the order via an index